# 301 redirect an entire folder but keep dynamic urls intact

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory that was mislabeled.

Example:  www.example.com/badfolder

It should've been:  www.example.com/goodfolder

Within the directory, there are tons of dynamic urls and friendly urls.

I'd like to put a line in my .htaccess file in the public_html folder that redirects to the new folder.

Therefore, it someone was navigating to:  www.example.com/badfolder/page.php?id=123&x=5&y=10

It would redirect to:  www.example.com/goodfolder/page.php?id=123&x=5&y=10

Is this correct?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^badfolder/(.*)?$ /goodfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have works fine for me. You just need to make sure it's closer to the top of your htaccess file, above any other internally rewriting rules that you may have.

Alternatively, you can stick with mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /badfolder /goodfolder
```

and it'll do the same thing.

Comment: Actually, you bring up another point I was worried about.  The pages within either folder are subject to other mod_rewrite rules to deal with friendly urls and such.  If I put the rewrite rule at the top the htacess file, then the page is redirected, will it still then loop through the htaccess file to look for any other rewrite rules that might apply?

Comment: @Kevin It won't in this case because it's an external redirect, so the new URL is processed on a separate request

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I went with the mod_rewrite because it was behaved better with the other htaccess stuff i had going on.